Can the past tense be used to describe events that happened after the moment of utterance?
Suppose there are two events in what you are going to say. For example, in the listening part of an exam:

In this section, you will hear two long conversations. At the end of each conversation, you will hear four questions about what was said.

or

I'm going to tell you some news. Tell me how you feel after I said (?) it/after you heard it.

Should the past tense ("was said" & "said/heard") be used in these examples instead of the simple present or the future perfect?
If the use of tense here is correct, does it mean that the past tense can also describe events that happen in the future, since the recording of the conversation has not been played yet?
If so, is the choice of tense determined by the order of the two events in what you say, or by the order of each events in relation to the time you say the sentence?
By the way, I'm aware that the preterite is sometimes used in the subjunctive mood, but I think that is a different case.

This is a recording of a past event. Do not confuse the time of the playing of the recording, with the actual time of the event.

@fev What if it is not recorded but is instead said on the spot? I added another example. Am I still confusing anything now?

The future perfect sounds insane here - it's a tense that's very rarely used in English. Would you really prefer "At the end of each conversation, you will hear four questions about what will have been said."?

@StuartF No, I wouldn't! But I'm wondering which tense is the best and why.

The second example you give is really unidiomatic. A native might say "Tell me how you feel after you hear the news."

@fev You mean people would use the present tense (hear).

This is the normal tense used in temporal clauses introduced by after, when, as soon as etc. Will have said would be hypercorrect in your sentence, that is, it may respect the grammatical rule, but is never used in common language.

I would say"Tell me how you feel when you've heard it".
